# How to quote strings in file names in zsh (passing back to other scripts)

Tags: zsh

I have a script that has a string in a file name like so:

```
filename_with_spaces="a file with spaces"
echo test > "$filename_with_spaces"
test_expect_success "test1: filename with spaces" "
  run cat \"$filename_with_spaces\"
  run grep test \"$filename_with_spaces\"
"
```

`test_expect_success` is defined as:

```
test_expect_success () {
  echo "expecting success: $1"
  eval "$2"
}
```

and `run` is defined as:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# make nice filename removing special characters, replace space with _
filename=`echo $@ | tr ' ' _ | tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9_.'`.run
echo "#!/bin/zsh" > $filename
print "$@" >> $filename
chmod +x $filename
./$filename
```

But when I run the toplevel script `test_expect_success`... I get `cat_a_file_with_spaces.run` with:

```
#!/bin/zsh
cat a file with spaces
```

The problem is the quotes around `a file with spaces` in `cat_a_file_with_spaces.run` is missing.  How do you get Z shell to keep the correct quoting?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
run cat ${(q)filename_with_spaces}
```

. It is what (q) modifier was written for. Same for run script:

```
echo -E ${(q)@} >> $filename
```

. And it is not bash, you don't need to put quotes around variables: unless you specify some option (don't remember which exactly)

```
command $var
```

always passes exactly one argument to `command` no matter what is in `$var`. To ensure that some zsh option will not alter the behavior, put

```
emulate -L zsh
```

at the top of every script.

Note that initial variant (`run cat \"$filename_with_spaces\"`) is *not* a correct quoting: filename may contain any character except NULL and `/` used for separating directories. `${(q)}` takes care about it.

**Update**: I would have written test_expect_success function in the following fashion:

```
function test_expect_success()
{
    emulate -L zsh
    echo "Expecting success: $1" ; shift
    $@
}
```

Usage:

```
test_expect_success "Message" run cat $filename_with_spaces
```

Comment: @ZyX, good tips but I still can't get it to work.  If I use (q) modifiers everywhere I end up getting `eval 'run\ cat\ a\\\ file\\\ with\\\ spaces'`.  Then if I switch `eval` back to `eval $2` I get `eval 'run cat a\ file\ with\ spaces'` which looks correct but `cat` gets 4 files instead of 1 with spaces.  It looks like `eval` is removing an extra level of quoting.  I confirm this with `eval "cat a\ file\ with\ spaces"` on the command line (cat gets 4 files).

Comment: My `eval` does not do it: `function Echo() { echo ${(pj.|.)@} } ; eval 'Echo abc\ def ghi'` echoes `abc def|ghi` as expected. By the way, see my the way of writing `test_expect_success` function in updated answer.

Comment: @ZyX: For your updated `test_expect_function` I can't take out `$1` because `test_expect_success` takes a script (multiple commands inside a quoted string of one argument)...sorry I should have included that in the initial question; I was trying to simplify my code.  Perhaps there is a better way to pass a script to another function.  I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @Slothman Don't know what is the problem with escaping arrays, but `${(qq)@}` works fine while with `${(q)@}` nothing is escaped.

Comment: @Slothman Got it. It is `echo` and `print` who are removing additional level of backslashes. Don't use `print ${(qq)@}`, use `echo -E ${(q)@}`.

Comment: @ZyX you got it, thanks!  I'm new here, do you update your answer?

Comment: @Slothman Yes. There is a link after «edited», it points to a list of revisions and makes you able to see what I changed. Don't remember though whether or not it requires to have some amount of reputation.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify that `test_expect_success` takes a script for `$2`.

Comment: @Slothman. By the way, why do you create these wrapper scripts?